# How to align checkbox and input filed/edittext widget to be on the same horizontal level

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

[image]as shown in the screenshot attached, the input field or the edit text widget is appearing beneath the checkbox. I want to display all of the elements on the same line.
I tried to modify the css file but never gets the desired results.
please let me know how to align the edit text/input field to be on the same level with the check-box and the info button

**html code**:

```
<div id="select-pesticides-types-menu" *ngIf="showPesticidesTypesMenu">
                    <label class="clr-pesticides-control-label">{{ "SITE.PESTICIDES.LABEL" | translate}}</label>
                    <clr-toggle-container>
                        <clr-toggle-wrapper>
                            <input type="checkbox" clrCheckbox  (change)="toggleShowPesticide1()"  [(checked)]="showPesticide1"/>
                            <label >
                                {{ "SITE.PESTICIDES.TYPE_1" | translate }} 
                                <clr-input-container id="pesticides-specifications">
                                    <input 
                                        required
                                        maxlength="25"
                                        clrInput
                                        [(ngModel)]="sele"
                                        type="text"
                                        name="name"
                                    />
                                </clr-input-container>
                                <button id= "pesticide-type-help-info-icon" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon" (click)="showInformation('SERVICE_DISTANCE_MEASUREMENT')">
                                    <clr-icon shape="help-info" class="is-solid"></clr-icon>
                                </button>
                        </label>
                        </clr-toggle-wrapper>
                    </clr-toggle-container>
                </div>
```

**css**:

```
#pesticides-specifications{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 40x;
  right:0px;
  left:30px;
  padding: 15px;

  width: 10px;
  height:5px;
}
#select-pesticides-types-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right:340px;
  padding: 15px;

  width: 370px;
  height: 500;

  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: .15rem;
  background-color: white;

  z-index:2; 
  cursor: pointer; 
}
```

**img**:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: have you tryed adding "display:flex" as style of the main div?
<div style="display: flex" id="select-pesticides-types-menu" *ngIf="showPesticidesTypesMenu">

Answer (score 0):

U can use only CSS if you want to align, Checkbox, The Text and The info Button

```
clr-toggle-wrapper{
 display:flex;
 align-items: center;
}

label {
 display:flex;
 align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: should i keep the css file as it is without change or should i change something

Comment: this would be more responsive, just add classes on label and this other div parent,  and you can see the changes, they you can add more stuff to child tags if you want